# Getting href value in ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, filter, tags, href

Can anyone point out my mistake in trying to find the value of a href attribute of  tag which contains "123456" within it?

```
                $('input').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                            type : "GET",
                            url : 'transfer.html',
                            dataType : "html",
                            success: function(data) {
                                alert($(data).filter('a[href*="123456"]').attr('href'));
                            },
                            error : function() {
                                    alert("Sorry, The requested property could not be found.");
                            }
                    });
            });
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: p.s. I've tried a 1000 different ways but I'm not gonna put them all up here! none of them worked for me! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I needed to get the table first and then ".find" the particular a tag href value.

Like this:

```
var table = $(data).find('table.className');
                                var a     = table.find('a[href*="123456"]');
                                var href  = a.attr("href");
                                alert(href);
```

Thanks for helping guys! This is the best website since Hulu.com ;)